# Print 2D Array as a Method in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, methods

I want to write a method in C++ which prints a 2D array. This method is void and it has these parameters as inputs: 2D array, number of rows, number of columns. I want to use the 2D matrix as a double pointer to call the function. I want to print the elements in a 2D shape. I get the following error:

`error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[2]’ to ‘int**’`

EDIT : changing int** list to int (*list)[2] works but is there a way which I don't have to write the column number manually, because I want this method to work for different sizes of array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray2D(int** list, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cout << list[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int list1[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };

    int row1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    
    int col1 = sizeof(list1[0]) / sizeof(list1[0][0]);

    printArray2D(list1, row1, col1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is actually flat, meaning that you have to cast its type to `int*`, not to `int**`. `int**` refers to array of pointers to int arrays, but you have no pointers inside array.

In other words you have actually 1-dimensional array of ints (flat). Any C multi-dimensional array like `int a[3][5]` or `int a[3][5][7]` are all flat array, 1-dimensional in nature. `[3][5]` array points to contiguous region in memory containing `3 * 5 = 15` ints, and `[3][5][7]` array points to `3 * 5 * 7 = 105` ints in contiguous region of memory.

Also after casting to `int*` information about dimensions is lost, hence you have to do indexing arithmetics manually through using `[i * col + j]`:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDfasMgFMbvfYpDd5M0jjVd75INBnuLkAsxthgSDWo2tuCzZ0clhXQi@Km/7/zj0/TMB6Zu6/okFR/mTkAttXVGsPGdkNlKdQPFRmEnxgVY11WEfGnZwWSkch/GsJ/zZ4byCIO0jgJKMPo7Ca6HHBYCuK7aQOBAwhucKjzqwKEoio3ZcX3ieuQwDIo9FxbXs4O6jpkbCccAQgF9Gx4PcKjutCePHqG6If174gkJGUcmVZaTlCM8hLhlc25xYzELLCU9e7q80osHj4PYOOyjRMDKX6GvWXTl8LK7N6c2T@nuLiz20RWo/8bkjb7d1OPY80jRWAONMTfWCDcbhTPE/mBd/wA)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray2D(int* list, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cout << list[i * col + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int list1[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };

    int row1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    
    int col1 = sizeof(list1[0]) / sizeof(list1[0][0]);

    printArray2D((int*)list1, row1, col1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 
3 4
```

---

Actually there is a C++ specific solution using templates that can be used to keep information about dimensions and forward this information to function, then you don't have to use manual indexing arithmetics:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDfa8MgEMff/SuODkZCM9ZmfUtWGNtfsFfJgxhbDEaDmpUt@LdnXlwL6Q7B@/H53unxYXjiiunzPD9IzdXYCqilcd4K1h8JGZ3UZ9CsF25gXIDzbUWIF/2gmEdUe/g0F1cAeu9GuSP5MrKFwcbEm7Xsu/zIsMaNdh6yRyWdzylqGop8k8NEINrJWFhICa@wq@JVL62jt91eoRXYJbCLIHaK3hpE42b0UNeAY6lsaNdgtIFNdcMCuYeFblWqBxIIwVk9kzrLSWqOCWy4p2UTT3zGBNO@KEMxvRSHACHu6MpZc9lHwMkfYU7ZosrheRXTXZOncTcVN@pehdR/YdIuutXK06C/ihV@tDruKv4G5vkX)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int Rows, int Cols>
void printArray2D(int const (&list)[Rows][Cols]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++) {
            cout << list[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int list1[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };

    int row1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    
    int col1 = sizeof(list1[0]) / sizeof(list1[0][0]);

    printArray2D(list1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 
3 4
```

---

Another nice solution in case if you have fixed multi-dimensional array is by using [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Then you don't need to forward any dimensions information, just use `.size()` method of `std::array`:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/8rdEvsYPz)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename ArrT>
void printArray2D(ArrT const & list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << list[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> list1 =
        { std::array{1,2}, std::array{3,4} };
    printArray2D(list1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 
3 4
```

Comment: I am using list as a pointer so I can call all the elements by using one index because all the array values are adjacent to each other in the memory. Is it correct?

Comment: @user6210457 Yes, correctly. If you have `int a[3][5]` or `int a[3][5][7]` in all cases of multi-dimensional C arrays they all are actually 1-dimensional, meaning that array variable is just a pointer to single memory region containing all array data, it is flat in this sence. If you have dimensions `[3][5][7]` then you have just a contiguous area of memory containing `3 * 5 * 7 = 105` ints in one region of memory.

Comment: @user6210457 I just added second part of my answer with C++ specific solution using templates, please put a look at it. It is a nice workaround to avoid passing dimensions sizes like row/col to function. Also it helps not to do any manual indexing arithmetics, you can just use `[i][j]`.

Comment: @user6210457 Again, just added third part of my answer with `std::array` solution, please put a look. This `std::array` solution is very C++-ish, because using C array `int a[3][5]` is closer to C-style, while `std::array` is a modern C++ variant of same array as C array.

Comment: 2D (3D etc) arrays are represented in the memory as flat contiguous arrays. Despite this fact, accessing 2D arrays as 1D is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Why it is undefined behaviour? Because some C compilers may make 2D/3D array non-contiguous? Or place it not row-major, but column-major order? Don't know any example of this. Or it is Undefined Behaviour only because compilers are free to implement memory layout of array the way the like?

Comment: No, arrays are always contiguous and row-major, exactly as you would expect. It is still undefined because the standard says so.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Does standard explain why it is considered to be undefined behaviour? Is it due to standard leaving some space for future modifications of compilers when layout of array may change? Or maybe because standard doesn't say that it should be implemented in congiguous/row-major form in all compilers? Because if in standard it is strictly said somewhere that array is always contiguous and always row-major, then I don't see any reason why such restriction is not equal to strictly defined behaviour?Only two facts that it is row major and contiguous are enough for defined...

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. "Because the standard says so": Where?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm asking that because by the same logic it would already be UB to access `p[1]` for an `int *p` because, you know, it's exceeding the boundaries of the object `p` points to!

Comment: @Arty Nope, there is no explanation.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica For one, [An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4). So there is nothing that gives you license to write `(int*)list1` and then access it. For two, [pointer arithmetic is only defined within the array object that the pointer points to an element of](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2). If `p` points to `list[0][0]`, you can only do indexing within `list[0]` because `list[0][0]` is an element of `list[0]`, not an element of `list[1]` or `list` or anything.

Comment: @Arty I just read the answer n. linked to, and the standard discussion linked to from there. It's quite instructive. Originally even `struct A{int i;} a; A *pa = (A*)&a.i;` (converting between a pointer to the first member of a class and a pointer to class) should be forbidden, but that would invalidate too much existing C code (e.g. [struct sockaddr address hacks](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)). Apparently a lot of concern goes to enabling compiler optimizations based on excluding access paths to data (thus avoiding expensive memory syncs).